# Multiple select category field not re-populating after failed validation on submission

Tags: c#, validation, razor, model-view-controller, multi-select

I have a multi select dropdown option that allows you to select as many values as you want. The form and validation seems to be working as expected, but I noticed if I have more than one multi select options "selected" (say 5 selected) and the form fails after validation, the multi select only returns 1 selected option back after validation. It seems the validation can only return 1 value no matter what. How do I get the form to return all selected values after a failed form validation? (say all 5 selected)

I tried adding special logic that passes the category array into the MultiSelect overload. In theory this should work, but it does not seem to reflect those values in the view? What is the best approach to get all multi select values to get returned after a failed validation submission.

I added a few screenshots to help better understand along with my Controller and View code.

**Before Submission**
[image: Before Submission]

**After Submission** (note the missing Report Category fields)
[image: After Submission]

**Controller**

```
  private void getReportCategoryList(int[] categoryIds){

            //New Multi Select List. Gets all category combinations 
            var categories = db.Report_Category_NEW.Select(c => new
            {
                CategoryID = c.ReportCategoryID,
                CategoryName = c.ReportCategory
            }).OrderBy(c => c.CategoryName).ToList();

            //Place Categories in ViewData for View()
            if(categoryIds == null)
            {
            //If categoryIds is null, no categoryIds to pre populate
                ViewData["Categories"] = new MultiSelectList(categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
            }
            else
            {
            //If categoryIds is NOT null, pre populate the MultiSelectList using the categoryIds array
                ViewData["Categories"] = new MultiSelectList(categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", categoryIds);
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
                  <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Report_Category, "Report Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryIds", (MultiSelectList)ViewData["Categories"], new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "select2 form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryIds, "", new { @class = "badge badge-default badge-danger text-left" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```